# Exchange 2010 console and shell not connecting after a fresh install

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

> VERBOSE: Connecting to
>   EXCHANGE01.domain.com
>   [exchange01.domain.com]
>   Connecting to remote server failed
>   with the following error message : The
>   WinRM client can not process the
>   request. It cannot determine the
>   content type of the HTTP response from
>   the destination computer. The content
>   type is absent or invalid. For more
>   information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help
>   topic.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError:
>   (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace)
>   [], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed

This is what I get in the shell, something similar I see when I try to login to the GUI
googling provides a lot of information, mosly irrelevant. For example http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2010/02/04/453946.aspx has a lot of info, but the described options do not appear in my system at all (the powershell part in IIS has no KerbAuth option at all)

UPD: fixed by removing and installing the WinRM feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by removing and installing the WinRM feature